# After two UK visa refusals, can I apply again?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

I have been refused a UK visa for the second time this year. Can I reapply or do I have to wait for a few years before I reapply? I am a Ghanaian.

> The decision:
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 – V4.10 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for visitors because you applied on 19/04/2018 to enter the United Kingdom on 01/05/2018 in order to attend the RBTE event at Olympia on 2-3/05/2018.
>
> Your application was received under our Standard Process and our service agreement is that we will deal with such applications in 15 working days from receipt. We have met that time limit but your application was received too late for us to meet that before your date of planned entry to the United Kingdom and I note that the event you intended visiting has already taken place. This means that the stated reason for your visit is no longer valid.
>
> You state that you are employed by Seaweld with a monthly income of GHS XXXXX (£xxx). You appear to have no dependants or assets in Ghana. I am not satisfied you have shown that, on the balance of probabilities, your ties to Ghana (or elsewhere) are such that you will leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit. I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit.
>   Paragraph V 4.2 (a) (c) of the Immigration Rules.

The first refusal reason is below:

> The decision
>
> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) 4.2, of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
>
> You have applied for leave to enter to visit the UK for 20 days.
>
> You have stated that you are employed and that your total monthly income from all sources of employment after tax is xxx.xx (currency unspecified). I have noted all of the documents you have submitted in support of your application including your work certificate and payslips which appear to
>   support your statements.
>
> However, whilst I have noted these, the remaining documents you have submitted do not demonstrate that you receive your stated monthly income; how you financially support yourself or that you hold any other personal assets, property or savings as the bank statement you provided shows that you received twice your salary xxxx.xx GHS (£xxx.xx oanda at exchange rate on 5/04/2018) when no salary appear to have been transferred into your account in January 2018 and March 2018.
>
> The above means, I am not satisfied that your personal or financial circumstances are as stated or of your true intentions for wishing to visit the UK now. I am not therefore satisfied that you are a genuine visitor and will leave the UK at the end of your visit. Your application for a visit visa has been refused under Paragraph V4.2(a)(c).
>
> You have submitted bank statements in support of your circumstances in Ghana and in support of your claim to having funds in place for this visit. However as stated above, they do not confirm you receive your stated monthly income nor do they confirm the origin of your funds. The above means I am not satisfied that these funds are genuinely available to you for your exclusive use. I am not therefore satisfied that you have sufficient funds available to cover your costs whilst in the UK
>   without working or accessing public funds. Your application has therefore been refused under Paragraph V4.2(e).

Answer (score 12):

There is nothing to stop you reapplying but rapid applications with a different reason every time will undermine the chances of success and may lead to a ban for frivolous applications. Your best option is to wait before reapplying and in the meantime concentrate on addressing the shortfalls in your application, particularly ties to your home country. This answer provides more enlightenment [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) As the answer above advises, advice from an immigration lawyer would probably be advisable when submitting your next application.

Comment: How do i get myself an immigration lawyer ?

Comment: @GeorgeCofie Pay him? Don't know about your country, but in mine lawyers advertise just like any other business.

Comment: @George Cofie Note: this might be stating the obvious, but an immigration lawyer can review your paperwork for shortcomings, not provide a miracle fix - he/she can’t magic up ties to your home country or substantiate your financial circumstances in the absence of valid bank statements etc., or remove Ghana from the list of countries with a high immigration risk.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to wait, but with two consecutive refusals you really need a lawyer with UK immigration experience.

You don't mention anything about the other refusal. What were the reasons for that one?

Comment: I have attached the other reason

Comment: How do i get an Immigration Lawyer?

Comment: Website of the Immigration law practitioners association might help you find a lawyer http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/find-immigration-advice.html